# How to Convert DateTime.Now in 0 to 1 decimal format in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, format, decimal

I would like to convert the current time to a decimal representing a fraction of the day. For example, if the day starts at 0, then 12:00 PM should be 0.5.

I need to send that value to an API, and it needs to be in that format. i.e.

```
"LAST_PRINT_TIME":0.22020833"
```

Comment: I meant "if the day starts at 0, 12 pm should be .5 format"

Comment: 12pm is ambigious, but I take your meaning, 24 hours = 1  - I'm curious how do leap seconds work in this world?

Comment: Weclome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] showing your problem.

Comment: IIRC, Excel uses such a format. The date is the value in front of the decimal sepereator, hours to seconds are the ones behind.

Comment: `DateTime`'s `ToOADate` method will return a `double` value where midnight is a whole number and  noon is at `x.5` (just subtract the whole part).

Comment: @Christopher: Indeed, what Excel uses is the OA (OLE Automation) Date, although there's a slight variation between Excel and .NET due to differences in leap...something...something; it ends up off by a day or two in the early values.

Comment: @madreflection I remember. Excel faultily considers 1900 a leap year. The rule for leapyears was: Every year divisible by 4. Years divisible by 100 do not count, unless they are also divisble by 400.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right (about how it's wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the precision requirements of your result, this may help you:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
double dayFraction = (now.Hour + now.Minute / 60d) / 24d;
```

`now.Minute / 60d` calculates the fraction of the current hour (so if the time is XX:15 PM this will give 0.25).  This is then added to the current hour.  This value is then divided by 24 to obtain the final result.

For example, 3:45 PM would go as follows:
`(15 + 45 / 60) / 24)` => `(15 + 0.75) / 24` => `15.75 / 24` => `0.65625`

So 3:45 PM, which is 15.75 hours into the day, would be 0.65625 (or 65.625%) of the day.

---

Or, as @madreflection mentioned in a comment, you could use `.ToOADate()` as well.  In this case, you could do something like:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
double dayFraction = now.ToOADate() - now.Date.ToOADate();
```

Comment: To attempt to minimize floating-point errors, you can subtract `now.Date.ToOADate()` instead of using `Math.Floor` or `Math.Truncate`.

Comment: @madreflection Good point, I'll edit to include. Feel free to edit as well if needed

Comment: I will, but I like to allow the original author a chance to put their own voice on it until they're done.

Comment: I appreciate it; it's you're suggestion, though, and I have to admit I wouldn't have come up with it on my own. If you want, I'll remove it from my answer and you can post it as yours

Comment: No, keep it. I'm okay with it.

Comment: Thank you Guys, I appreciate your response.

Comment: @elmer007 it looks this did the work, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those problems that seems deceptively simple, but the solution is actually much more complex than you would think.

The complexities arise from the nature of local time, whose rules are defined by *time zones*. Many time zones have *transitions* that occur either regularly (such as for [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info)), or irregularly (such as for changes in standard time).

As such, one needs to consider:

- Could the day be shorter or longer than 24 hours?

  - For example, in most of the US the start of DST is at 2:00 AM, and on that day there are 23 hours in the day because the hour from 2:00 to 2:59 is skipped.  At the end of DST, also at 2:00 AM in the US, the hour from 1:00 through 1:59 is repeated, creating 25 hours in that day.
- Could the day start or stop at a time other than midnight?

  - For example, [in most of Chile in 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/chile?year=2019), the start of DST made the date `2019-09-08` start at `01:00` instead of `00:00`.

Learn more in [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Consider using the following approach to overcome these real-world considerations.

First, define some helper functions to do most of the work.  They are not specific to a particular point in time or a particular time zone.

```
static double GetFractionOfDay(DateTimeOffset dto, TimeZoneInfo tz)
{
    // Get the start of the day, and the start of the next day
    DateTimeOffset startOfDay = GetStartOfDay(dto, tz);
    DateTimeOffset startOfNextDay = GetStartOfDay(startOfDay.AddDays(1), tz);

    // Calculate the length of the day.  It might not be 24 hours!
    TimeSpan lengthOfDay = startOfNextDay - startOfDay;

    // Now calculate the position within the day, and the fraction to return
    TimeSpan durationSinceStartOfDay = dto - startOfDay;
    return durationSinceStartOfDay / lengthOfDay;
}

static DateTimeOffset GetStartOfDay(DateTimeOffset dto, TimeZoneInfo tz)
{
    // Make sure we're in the correct time zone
    dto = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dto, tz);

    // Start by assuming a local midnight exists
    DateTime dt = dto.Date;

    // Handle days without a local midnight (these do exist in several time zones)
    if (tz.IsInvalidTime(dt))
    {
        // Advance by the transition gap.  This is usually 1 hour, but best not to hard-code that.
        TimeSpan[] offsets = { tz.GetUtcOffset(dt.AddDays(-1)), tz.GetUtcOffset(dt.AddDays(1)) };
        TimeSpan gap = offsets[1] - offsets[0];
        return new DateTimeOffset(dt.Add(gap), offsets[1]);
    }

    // Handle days with more than one midnight (it's possible, even if unlikely)
    if (tz.IsAmbiguousTime(dt))
    {
        // There's more than one.  Prefer the first one, since we want the beginning of the day.
        TimeSpan[] offsets = tz.GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets(dt);
        TimeSpan offset = offsets[0] > offsets[1] ? offsets[0] : offsets[1];
        return new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
    }

    // Clean case, just one local midnight and it does exist
    return new DateTimeOffset(dt, tz.GetUtcOffset(dt));
}
```

With those defined, you can now get an answer to your question with regard to "now" in the local time zone.

```
double dayFraction = GetFractionOfDay(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

***However*** - Though this is the correct answer of "what fraction of the day is it", keep in mind it may be more important to align with what the receiving API expects, even if not exactly correct.  In other words, if `12:00` should *always* be `0.5`, even when it's not exactly at the midpoint of the day, then use [elmer007's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58550133/634824) approach.

Comment: Jonson-Pint this is great info as well, I will analyze the code. Thanks